# CSS not showing on Github pages

Tags: github-pages

My CSS is not showing. This is my first time using Github Pages and I'm really confused.

The link to the site is: https://jevoncochran.github.io/index.html
The link to the repo is: https://github.com/jevoncochran/jevoncochran.github.io

I tried playing around with the CSS link in the html file

this is what I have now:

Comment: Your css is not in a folder, change the path from 'css/index.css' to just 'index.css'

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In your index.html, the above line should be:

```
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: That didn't work. All it did was take away my CSS entirely. When I did that, not only does it not show up on Github Pages, it stops showing up when I open the file in the browser directly from VS Code.

Comment: Are you coding in VS and then pushing the changes to gitHub or are you making changes directly in github? How are your files arranged in your local environment? Is the index.css in a css folder?

Comment: In the local environment, the index.css is in a css folder. I was coding in VS and then pushing the changes to gitHub.

Comment: ok. I am not sure why your css file was not pushed to the gitHub without being in the folder. Are you pushing the files using gitBash or are you manually adding them to gitHub Upload Files link?

Comment: put a "/" before your css file